# Google Sheets Creates Random Cell Border with onEdit Function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm having a weird issue where Google Sheets keeps drawing a mysterious, seemingly random cell border within the same range, over and over when an onEdit function is called. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on.

**DETAILS**

If a specific range is edited (Selection Box), an onEdit function is called to make some basic background color changes to a few other ranges. All of these color changes are working. However, an additional vertical border is also drawn within another range (Range With Problem).

One thing to keep in mind in this example is that nowhere in the script is setBorder even being used. The borders you see being created are something that Google Sheets is doing, it is not happening as a result of the code.

***This shows the problem range highlighted in Blue before the selection is made:***

[image]

***This shows the vertical border as drawn after the selection is made:***

[image]

```
    ////////////////////////////////////////////   Sheet Variables

var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var sheetName = sheet.getName();

////////////////////////////////////////////  Top Box Variables 

var bigBox = sheet.getRange("B2");
var selectionBox = sheet.getRange("E3");
var top_Headers = sheet.getRange("E2:AI2");
var top_Stats = sheet.getRange("M3:AI3");

////////////////////////////////////////////   Bottom Box Variables

var statArray_Range = sheet.getRange("E6:J11");
var stat1_Range = sheet.getRange("E6:E11");
var stat2_Range = sheet.getRange("H6:H11");
var stat3_Range = sheet.getRange("J6:J11");
var last_Cell = "AI11";
var all_Cells = sheet.getRange("C6:"+last_Cell);

////////////////////////////////////////////   Arrays

var array_1 = ["FOO_green","BAR_green"];
var array_2 = ["FOO_red","BAR_red"];

////////////////////////////////////////////   Colors

var darkGreen = "#b6d7a8";
var lightGreen = "#d9ead3";
var darkRed = "#ea9999";
var lightRed = "#f4cccc";
var darkBlue = "#9fc5e8";
var lightBlue = "#cfe2f3";
var gray = "#efefef";
var lightGray = "#f3f3f3";

////////////////////////////////////////////   Data Validation

// --------------------------------------------------------- 
//    Create dropdown based on values in the sheet 'Data'
// ---------------------------------------------------------

var rule = app.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(ss.getSheetByName("Data").getRange("A1:A4"),false).build();
selectionBox.setDataValidation(rule);

////////////////////////////////////////////   Stored Variables

// --------------------------------------------------------- 
//    Create variable to track the last selection made
// ---------------------------------------------------------

function initializeProperties(){

  var script_Properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  if(selectionBox.isBlank())
  {
      script_Properties.setProperty("option_Selected","EMPTY");
  }
  else if(selectionBox.getValue().includes("FOO"))
  {
      script_Properties.setProperty("option_Selected","FOO");
  }
  else
  {
      script_Properties.setProperty("option_Selected","BAR");
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function onEdit(event){                                                   //           ON EDIT             //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    script_Properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    oldValue = script_Properties.getProperty("option_Selected");

    // --------------------------------------------------------- 
    //    Define onEdit Event Variables
    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    range = event.range;
    inputValue = event.value;
    cell = range.getA1Notation();
    row = range.getRow();
    col = range.getColumn();

    // --------------------------------------------------------- 
    //    If Selection drop down is range edited
    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    if(col == "5" && row == "3")
    {      
    updateBGColor(inputValue);

    // --------------------------------------------------------- 
    //    Reset entire sheet - clear backgrounds and values
    // --------------------------------------------------------- 

    if(inputValue == null)
    {
      oldValue = script_Properties.setProperty("option_Selected","EMPTY");
      resetAll();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------- 
    //    If Selection made is 'BAR_green' or 'BAR_red'
    // --------------------------------------------------------- 

    else if(inputValue.includes("BAR"))
    {
      statArray_Range.setValue(null);
      statArray_Range.setBackground(null);

      if(oldValue != "BAR")
      {
        oldValue = script_Properties.setProperty("option_Selected","BAR");
        statArray_Range.setValue(null);
      }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------- 
    //    If Selection made is 'FOO_green' or 'FOO_red'
    // --------------------------------------------------------- 

    else if(inputValue.includes("FOO"))
    {
      statArray_Range.setValue("---");
      stat2_Range.setscript_PropertiesValidation(null);
      stat3_Range.setscript_PropertiesValidation(null);
      statArray_Range.setValue("---");
      statArray_Range.setBackground(lightGray);
      
      if(oldValue != "FOO")
      {
        oldValue = script_Properties.setProperty("option_Selected","FOO");
      }
    }
  }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function updateBGColor(x){                                        //        UPDATE BACKGROUND COLOR          //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // --------------------------------------------------------- 
    //    If Selection made is "FOO_green" or "BAR_green"
    // --------------------------------------------------------- 

    if(array_1.includes(x))
    {   
        bigBox.setBackground(darkGreen);
        top_Headers.setBackground(lightGreen);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------- 
    //    If Selection made is "FOO_red" or"BAR_red"
    // --------------------------------------------------------- 

    else if(array_2.includes(x))
    {
        bigBox.setBackground(darkRed);
        top_Headers.setBackground(lightRed);      
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------- 
    //    If Selection is Deleted
    // --------------------------------------------------------- 

    else if(x == undefined)
    {   
        bigBox.setBackground(gray);
        top_Headers.setBackground(gray);      
    }
    else{
        bigBox.setBackground(darkBlue);
        top_Headers.setBackground(lightBlue);
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function resetAll(){                                                     //         RESET ALL          //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    top_Stats.setValue(null);
    all_Cells.setValue(null);
    all_Cells.setBackground(null);
}
```

Hopefully one of you Javascript Gurus with more experience might be able to solve the mystery.

Thanks for your time...any help is greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I updated the original post with a more precise explanation of what the script should be doing. Hope this helps. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to make it easier for you to help.

Comment: Hi. It was somewhat confusing that showDropdown was false in requireValueInRange(). Because of this, the drop-down list in the cell disappeared when making changes. I had to re-select the checkbox in Data validation all the time.
I noticed that if you cancel the merging of cells in T5:V11 then the problem disappears.

Comment: In my browser I would just double click in the range and the drop down would show up. Setting showDropdown to false just hides the triangle but the drop down still works fine if you double click on the range. I have also noticed some weird things like you pointed out on unmerging the ranges. For example, if you change the last column of the top_Headers range to something before AI2, then that random border will be drawn at a different position.

Comment: Also noticed commenting out some things like the call to updateBGColor would stop the border from being drawn too but these are all things that shouldn't matter and definitely shouldn't draw some random border. I want to think there is a logical explanation but so far I can't find one.

Comment: Maybe put a breakpoint at the beginning of updateBGColor and see the variables (ranges)? To figure out why blue is applied to the border of the column T. Or log them.

Comment: Yeah I have done that with no success in finding anything that seems like the cause unfortunately. That's why I posted to Stack. I updated commenting in the code to make it easier to follow just now by the way. Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you using merged cells? That may be the issue. Have you tried making do without them?

Comment: You updated your code and an error appears. What is this function - setscript_PropertiesValidation?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties

Comment: Boris... this allows you to store data statically without it being reset each time the code is triggered. It is the only way to save information in this way that I am familiar with. See the link I provided above. I am not getting any errors with this. Where are you seeing them exactly?

Comment: This section is familiar to me, I use Properties, but there is no setscript_PropertiesValidation. Perhaps this is a typo?

Comment: Select FOO_green, see Runs, error: line 131, setscript_PropertiesValidation is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The issue is with Merged cells

If you have a merged range, say `A1:B2` then if you `getRange('B2')` it will actually select `A1`. Likewise, the Spreadsheet service will see this merged range as 4 different cells. You can think of the merged aspect of them as more of a UI thing, in the back-end, they are still treated much like 4 separate cells.

If you need to put a border around a merged range, then you would need to carefully select the whole range that the merged cell covers and set the *outside* borders.

```js
// setBorder(top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal, color, style)
range.setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
```

#### Reference

- [`setBorder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBorder(Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,String,BorderStyle))
- [`border style`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/border-style)

#### Edit

Around line 96

```js
    if(col == "5" && row == "3")
    {      
      updateBGColor(inputValue);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush() // ADD THIS LINE
```

[Flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) ensures that all edits are applied before moving on. Apps Script tries to batch these together for performance and sometimes, especially dealing with merged ranges and formats, this can lead to issues.

I usually stay away from merged ranges as much as possible! Though adding this line did fix the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I am sure this is not correct. I work with merged cells all the time and have no issues. I just updated all the code for merged cells, defining them using all cells and the issue persists. So this was not the problem. The one thing to keep in mind in this example is that nowhere in the script is setBorder or border style even being defined. The borders you see being created are something that Google Sheets is doing, it is not happening as a result of the code. This is the real problem. Trying to isolate what is causing Sheets to draw a border when one is not defined.

Comment: @nothingspecial  - gotcha,  I edited my answer with a possible fix, let me know if it works!

Comment: I had no idea Flush was even a thing wow. Yeah this works beautifully. I even added the line to the real script and it is working perfectly. Thanks so much. In what situations do you find it necessary to use Flush usually ?

Comment: After some debugging I was unable to pinpoint the exact line of code that caused the issue, it seemed to be the result of a combination of operations. This made me think that perhaps `flush` could solve it. If you are having to write a bunch of different things to the sheet, lots of times, and the subsequent operations read from the sheet (i.e. not in memory), then sometimes you need `flush`. Sometimes its just to increase reliability.